# infinite loop in onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) fn in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, infinite-loop

I have a code something like this:

```
change_status_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mfirebasedatabase.getReference().child("genre_items").child(genre_status_selected).child(genreitem_status_selected).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if(genre_status_selected!="" && genreitem_status_selected!="" && dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().equals("available"))
                        {
                            mfirebasedatabase.getReference().child("genre_items").child(genre_status_selected).child(genreitem_status_selected).child("status").setValue("unavailable");
                                                        }
                        else if(genre_status_selected!="" && genreitem_status_selected!="" && dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().equals("unavailable"))
                        {
                            mfirebasedatabase.getReference().child("genre_items").child(genre_status_selected).child(genreitem_status_selected).child("status").setValue("available");

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

whenever I click the change status button , it  changes the status ,but since it is in the onDataChange it leads to an infinite loop...changing its state infinite no of times...how to get rid of this? how to get out of this loop? I want to change its status once only.

Comment: The only solution I can think of is making a global variable of type `ValueEventListener`. Then you can set it and when something changes, you can remove the listener, change the value as you are already doing and set the listener back. By the way, you are comparing strings the wrong way; you should use `equals` to compare string objects

Comment: Use addListenerForSingleValueEvent instead of ValueEventListener. And why are you using a ValueEventListener inside onclick listener ?

Answer (score 2):

change

> addValueEventListener

to this

> addListenerForSingleValueEvent

```
mfirebasedatabase.getReference().child("genre_items").child(genre_status_selected).child(genreitem_status_selected).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if(genre_status_selected!="" && genreitem_status_selected!="" && dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().equals("available"))
                        {
                            mfirebasedatabase.getReference().child("genre_items").child(genre_status_selected).child(genreitem_status_selected).child("status").setValue("unavailable");
                                                        }
                        else if(genre_status_selected!="" && genreitem_status_selected!="" && dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().equals("unavailable"))
                        {
                            mfirebasedatabase.getReference().child("genre_items").child(genre_status_selected).child(genreitem_status_selected).child("status").setValue("available");

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  addListenerForSingleValueEvent()

example

```html
database.getReference().child("chats").child(senderRoom).child("messages").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            database.getReference("chats/"+senderRoom+"/messages").removeValue();
                            Toast.makeText(ChattingActivity.this, "All chats delete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(ChattingActivity.this, "Error! Chats not delete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
```